# Add one new column with current year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a data with 2 columns:

```
date                    weather  
4/25(Month & day)         10*
4/26                      8*
```

I am using `df.to_csv('path')` to open the csv file. The CSV file assumes the  data is in the dd-mm-yyyy format, so the whole output is going wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: open the csv file in notepad or another text editor. Are the values in fact incorrect or is it just the way excel is interpreting the data

Comment: So you want to add a column with the current year? Is it stored as string? As year param from Date object? I suggest you to use the strftime() method, but you should post the code with which you get the elements you want to add to the csv